# STS not running on Mac OS Catalina (version 10.15)

Tags: macos, spring-tool-suite

I have successfully downloaded STS-4 on Mac OS Catalina, but getting the following error when launching it:“SpringToolSuite4” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software. Anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.
Your post is not related to coding and would be better suited on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tofandel, STS (SpringToolSuite) - is an IDE where you write and execute your code in, and I believe the question is relevant to be asked here. There are a lot of similar questions related to IDE configuration and stuff on stackoverflow though, haven't you seen one before?

Comment: It is not relevant to coding because the IDE is not even installed yet and you are getting an apple warning related to any executable, not just the IDE..
A quick google search https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/install-spotify-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious-so

And as you can see it's on apple stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution prior to the just released 4.4.2 version was signed, but not yet notarized by Apple. macOS Catalina requires downloaded apps to be notarized in order to run them directly, therefore you get the mentioned error message.

Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse 4.4.2 got released today and is officially notarized, so you should be able to run that just as-is after downloading.

There also exists a workaround for older versions of the tooling, which can be found in the comments here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/375

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Martin, this sorted my problem

Answer (score 10):

Looks, it was because of a permission issue for me.
This helped me.
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app
[Link to refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295434/facing-permission-related-issues-in-macbook-pro-with-big-sur-11-4)