# Facing Permission related issues in MacBook pro with Big Sur 11.4

Tags: eclipse, macos, permissions, permission-denied, spring-tool-suite

Whenever I'm trying to open Eclipse or SpringToolSuite 4, I'm getting the same permission related issues It was working fine a day before yesterday but now It's showing weird stuff.

> You do not have permission to open the application “SpringToolSuite4”.

> You do not have permission to open the application “Eclipse”.

If anyone has any solutions please share

Comment: Check if this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842819/cant-run-app-because-of-permission-in-big-sur/64895860#64895860) helps

Comment: nothing worked tried almost everything

Comment: interestingly, I faced the same issue this morning. I don't know yet why, but re-installing a fresh copy of the distribution from the DMG file solved the issue for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run app because of permission in macOS v11 (Big Sur)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842819/cant-run-app-because-of-permission-in-macos-v11-big-sur)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The application has to be signed again

for Spring Tool Suite :

```
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app
```

for Eclipse :

```
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Synatx for signing application:

```
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/{app-name}.app
```

Comment: There's a more in-depth explanation about this on the apple developer site: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/684509

Answer (score 16):

As I faced, that re-installation only works for a couple of days, I was really happy about the the codesign statement, which also works for Eclipse.App itself:

```sh
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse.app
```

Comment: Has someone managed to deploy Eclipse designed for macbook M1? - Or its Intel version via Roseta2 is now the only way out?

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly on `Mac OS Big Sur (v 11.6)` with Eclipse `Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app

Answer (score 0):

no need to reinstall eclipse!!

1. install eclipse and plugins all u needed
2. if restart eclipse or restart mac, shows "You do not have permission to open the application",then mount the eclipse-xxx/springtoolsuit-xxx.dmg, show package(xx.app) contents, copy the “Info.plist”, Replace the file with the same name in your local eclipse.
   the eclipse will work again! even restart computer!!

Answer (score 0):

for Eclipse Java on apple silicon use this:

sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/Eclipse\ Java.app

or just drag app from Applications folder to terminal